# Passing values to a constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I am trying to pass the all the number of hours entered by the user Sunday - Saturday to any of the 3 constructors. I am unable to do so with the code that I have. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? ** FIXED **

```
public static TimeCard processTimeCard(String data)
{
   String[] split = data.split(",");
   String employee = split[0];
   String project = split[1];
   double rate = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);

   double hours = 0.0;

   String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
                      "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                      "Friday", "Saturday"};

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Get number of hours for each day of the week
   for (int index = 0; index < days.length; index++)
   {
       System.out.println("How many hours on " + days[index] + ".");
       hours += Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
   }

   TimeCard arrow = new TimeCard(employee, project, rate, hours);

   return arrow;

   }

}

class TimeCard
{
// Instance Variables
private String employeeName;
private String project;
private double rate;
private double hours;

//Class Variables
private static int numCards = 0;
private static final double OT_MULTIPLIER = 1.5;
private static final int OT_LIMIT = 40;


/**
* Constructor 1
*/
public TimeCard(String employee, String project, double rate, double hours)
{
    this.employeeName = employee;
    this.project = project;
    this.rate = rate;
    this.hours = hours;
    numCards++;
}

/**
 * Constructor 2
*/
public TimeCard(String employee, String project)
{
    rate = 0;
    hours = 0.0;
    numCards++;
}

/**
 * Constructor 3
*/
public TimeCard(String employee)
{
    project = "none";
    rate = 0;
    hours = 0.0;
    numCards++;
}

   /**
 * Accessors
*/
    public String getHours()
{
    return this.hours;
}
```

error I get is

```
   error: incompatible types
   return this.hours;

   required: String
   found; double
```

How do I fix this error

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You tell us.

Comment: What are you expecting from us here? To take your code, try to compile it. See if that results in an error. Then what, write unit tests for you too? You tell _us_ your error and we'll tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because it doesn't match any of your constructors. Compare `new TimeCard(employee, project, rate, hours)` to your various constructors and you'll see the parameters don't match.

Update constructor #1 (or create a new one) as follows:

```
public TimeCard(String employee, String project, double rate, double hours)
{
    this.employeeName = employee;
    this.project = project;
    this.rate = rate;
    this.hours = hours;
    numCards++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to pass the all the number of hours entered by the user Sunday - Saturday to any of the 3 constructors

I don't see that in your code.

I'm going to guess that you need to pass the total number of hours. With this, you're not doing that exactly:

```
hours = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
```

You read it but don't do anything with it. You can try adding all those hours up like so:

```
hours += Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
```

After you read all the hours, you can pass it to your constructor like so:

```
TimeCard arrow = new TimeCard(employee, project, rate, hours);
```

But make sure your main constructor accepts `hours` as a parameter:

```
/**
* Constructor 1
*/
public TimeCard(String employee, String project, double rate, double hours)
{
    this.employeeName = employee;
    this.project = project;
    this.rate = rate;
    this.hours = hours;
    numCards++;
}
```